# How to add ringtones to a RingtoneManager?

Tags: android

I would like to be able to add ringtone files, or perhaps even an entire folder path to the RingtoneManager so that it's cursor will contain more than just the default ringtones when I call the RINGTONE_PICKER action activity.

It sounds like a simple request, but there are no obvious methods in the RingtoneManager documentation (unless I'm blind), and no blatantly similar questions around here that I could find.

I have tried adding ringtone files (.ogg) directly to the the /system/media/ringtones/ folder in the emulator (I don't plan on rooting my physical phone), and the manager in the emulator still does not list them.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So after digging around for a bit, I learned that when using RINGTONE_PICKER:

if you set the RingtoneManager type to TYPE_RINGTONE

```
Intent intent = new Intent( RingtoneManager.ACTION_RINGTONE_PICKER);
intent.putExtra( RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TYPE,RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);
intent.putExtra( RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TITLE, "Select Tone");
startActivityForResult( intent, 0);
```

then the ringtone picker will add any viable audio files (mp3,ogg,etc...) that are located in ANY folder in the file system titled "ringtones" to it's pickable cursor.

if the RingtonManager type is set to TYPE_NOTIFICATION

```
intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TYPE,RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
```

then it will add any viable audio files located in ANY folder titled "notifications"

and finally if you set the type to TYPE_ALL it will display all audio files in folders named either "ringtones" or "notifications".

I hope this gives some clarity to anyone else out there!